# Write barcode in HTML Template tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

Please I need to replace the barcode in the template PDF,

**Code:**

```
$tmp_product = str_replace("{::prod_price}", $product['price'], $tmp_product);
$eancodes = $product['ean']; 
$eancode =  new TCPDFBarcode($eancodes, 'EAN13'); 
$tmp_product = str_replace("{::prod_ean}", $eancode, $tmp_product);
```

**Template HTML:**

```
 define('PDF_TEMPLATE_PROD', '  
<tr class="pdf_prod" id="{::prod_name}" nobr="true">         
  <td class="pdf_prod_desc">               
    <ul class="pdf_prod_ul">
      <li><strong>{::txt_prod_price}</strong> {::prod_price}</li>            
      <li class="pdf_prod_bcode">{::prod_ean}</li>
     </ul>
  </td> 
</tr>

');
```

Comment: It looks like all you need is to set $tmp_product to the value of `PDF_TEMPLATE_PROD` before your replace code. What happens when you add this just before your first str_replace: `$tmp_product = constant('PDF_TEMPLATE_PROD');`?

Comment: it makes no difference, still a problem

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What output are you seeing?

Comment: Unknown: Object of class TCPDFBarcode could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [TCPDFBarcode documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDFBarcode.html) documentation, the `TCPDFBarcode` class gives you a method that you can use to display the barcode:

- [`getBarcodeHTML`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDFBarcode.html#a80fd7768cceee724b5643c9697112522) - which returns an HTML representation of the barcode. You can insert this HTML directly into your `PDF_TEMPLATE_PROD` template

Using the `getBarcodeHTML` method you can do something like this:

```
// define the HTML template you'll use to markup the product data
define('PDF_TEMPLATE_PROD', '  
    <tr class="pdf_prod" id="{::prod_name}" nobr="true">         
        <td class="pdf_prod_desc">               
            <ul class="pdf_prod_ul">
                <li><strong>{::txt_prod_price}</strong> {::prod_price}</li>            
                <li class="pdf_prod_bcode">{::prod_ean}</li>
            </ul>
        </td> 
    </tr>

    ');

// pass the template into a variable where you'll fill in the data
$tmp_product = constant('PDF_TEMPLATE_PROD');
// insert the price
$tmp_product = str_replace("{::prod_price}", $product['price'], $tmp_product);

// extract the data you want to encode and create your TCPDFBarcode object:
$eancodes = $product['ean'];
$eancode =  new TCPDFBarcode($eancodes, 'EAN13'); 

// insert the HTML represenation of the barcode and print the result
$tmp_product = str_replace("{::prod_ean}", $eancode->getBarcodeHTML(), $tmp_product);
echo $tmp_product;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this works fine, Best Regards.